# draw2d: combine Manhatatn Interactive and Bridged routers

Tags: draw2d-js

I'm trying to combine interactive and bridged routers for my project. I created my own Router class, which inherits `InteractiveManhattanConnectionRouter`, where I overwrite `route` method, using code from `Bridged` router.

So far no luck, this is my attempt:

```
class CustomRouter extends draw2d.layout.connection.InteractiveManhattanConnectionRouter {

  init = function () {
    this._super();
  }

  route = (conn, routingHints) => {
    super.route(conn, routingHints);


    var intersectionsASC = conn.getCanvas().getIntersection(conn).sort("x");
    var intersectionsDESC = intersectionsASC.clone().reverse();
    var intersectionForCalc = intersectionsASC;
    var i = 0;

    var ps = conn.getVertices();
    var p = ps.get(0);
    var path = ["M", (p.x | 0) + 0.5, " ", (p.y | 0) + 0.5];
    var oldP = p;
    for (i = 1; i < ps.getSize(); i++) {
      p = ps.get(i);


      var bridgeWidth = 5;
      var bridgeCode = this.BRIDGE_HORIZONTAL_LR;

      if (oldP.x > p.x) {
        intersectionForCalc = intersectionsDESC;
        bridgeCode = this.BRIDGE_HORIZONTAL_RL;
        bridgeWidth = -bridgeWidth;
      }

      intersectionForCalc.each(function (ii, interP) {
        if (interP.justTouching) {
          return;
        }
        if (draw2d.shape.basic.Line.hit(1, oldP.x, oldP.y, p.x, p.y, interP.x, interP.y) === true) {
          if (Math.floor(p.y) === Math.floor(interP.y)) {
            console.log("pushon");

            path.push(" L", ((interP.x - bridgeWidth) | 0) + 0.5, " ", (interP.y | 0) + 0.5);
            path.push(bridgeCode);
          }
        }
      });

      path.push(" L", (p.x | 0) + 0.5, " ", (p.y | 0) + 0.5);
      oldP = p;
    }
    conn.svgPathString = path.join("");
  }
};
```

This doesn't show bridges, just behave as a regular Interactive router.